# _start definition in U-boot source

Tags: u-boot

I am understanding U-boot(v2014.07). 
In the start.S(at arch/arm/cpu/armv7/) file it is loading vector base address using following instructions.

```
ldr r0, =_start
mcr p15, 0, r0, c12, c0, 0  @Set VBAR
```

Can you please guide to understand where "_start" is defined. I checked in start.S and lowlevel_init.S, but I couldn't find.

Comment: When disassembly the start.o file, the "ldr r0, =_start" instruction is updated as "ldr r0, [pc, #104] ; 9c <cpu_init_crit+0x4>" . Can you please guide how to check where _start is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you please guide to understand where "_start" is defined

For the ARM architecture, **_start** is defined as a global in **arch/arm/lib/vectors.S**

> When disassembly the start.o file, the "ldr r0, =_start" instruction is updated as "ldr   r0, [pc, #104]  ; 9c " .

That should correspond to the first entry in the 32-byte ARM Exception vector, i.e.

```
    ldr pc, _reset
```

Comment: Thanks, I could see _start definition in arch/arm/lib/vectors.S.